# spring boot angular csrf token handshake error

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

So I keep on getting a error regarding a request from my fronted (angular) to my backend (springboot). I have a assumption that I don't send it correctly from my frontend to the backend.

spring security config:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository (this.getCsrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");

            }
        };
    }
    private CsrfTokenRepository getCsrfTokenRepository() {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        tokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
        return tokenRepository;
    }
```

angular requests:

```
 let url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/get_txt"
      this.http.get(url).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response)

        // post request

        
      let _csrf = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string == null ? "test":this.tokenExtractor.getToken();
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("name", "name")
      formData.append("_csrf", _csrf)
      let post = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/testpost"

      this.http.post(post, formData, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set("X-XSRF-TOKEN", _csrf),//.set("Cookie", 'XSRF-TOKEN='+_csrf)
      })
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
      })
```

proof that the request gets sent:
[sent csrf token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KK14.png)

What I also forget to mention is that I get a 403 error.
I would be thankfull for every support, but I dont't want to disable the csrf token and not remove the spring boot dependency ;)

how I get the token:

```
app.module.ts:

    import:[HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN'})]

app.component.ts
-> import
-> inject into constructor
let _csrf = this.tokenExtractor.getToken();
```

**Update**
I found out that spring boot is failing to extract the cookie from the request.
[image: spring boot extract cookie error]
So it has to be the fault of the angular request...

Comment: I think the header name is wrong. can you try with `X-CSRF-TOKEN`? e.g.: `headers: new HttpHeaders().set("X-CSRF-TOKEN", _csrf)`

Comment: @MarcoLucidi thanks for the suggestion, but sadly it also doesn't work....

Comment: @MarcoLucidi you were very close. Actually, header name should be X-XSRF-TOKEN.

Comment: Could you tell what version of Angular do you use?

Answer (score 0):

A header name that you send from Angular is intended for using as HTTP parameter. In your code it would be `let post = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/testpost?_csrf=" + _csrf`.
So when `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` is set as CSRF token repository and you want to send it as header then default header name for this token is `X-XSRF-TOKEN` ([as described here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-cookie)):

```
this.http.post(post, formData, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set("X-XSRF-TOKEN", _csrf)
})
...
```

Comment: thanks for the help @kemot90, but it still throws the error 403 even with the name of the token being X-XSRF-TOKEN and yes I also checkt that the token is not null, but it still doesn't work =(

Comment: So problem might be with token itself. Could you post how do you extract token with  `tokenExtractor.getToken()`?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem I think that spring boot somehow doesn't recognise it...

Comment: Try resend XSRF-TOKEN cookie in post request keeping X-XSRF-TOKEN header as well.